# This expression was expected to have type unit but here has a type 'a list

Tags: f#, unit-type

Here I have a function. In line `List.append [0] free_list` it is complaining that, `This expression was expected to have type unit but here has a type 'a list`, and it is not clear for me how does it infer that this statment must have an unit type.

```
let free_list=[]

let find_free_spaces  :List<int>=
   if  1=1                          // The condition is not important
   then  List.append [0] free_list
   free_list
```

Comment: Add `else` in front of last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F#, `if/then` and `if/then/else` are *expressions*, not *statements* (if you're coming from C#, `if x then y else z` is like `x ? y : z`).  If there's an `else` clause, then the type of that branch must match the type of the `if` branch so that the whole expression is well-typed.  If there is no `else`, then the `if`'s body must have type `unit`, since otherwise the result would just be disregarded (basically, `if x then y` is equivalent to `if x then y else ()`).

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is telling you that `List.append [0] free_list` returns a value of type `int list` but it expects your `if then` expression to be of `unit` type because you have no `else` condition.  If you added an `else` condition which also returned an `int list`, the compiler error would become a warning that you were ignoring the results of an expression.

F# is an expression rather than statement based language, that means `if then else...` etc return values (and consequently that those returned values *must* be of the same type in each case).

Also remember that F# lists are immutable so appending a list does not produce the side effect of adding values to an existing list, it creates a new list containing the original values and the appended values.

As it stands, your code would take a list, build a new list that contains 0 and the list you provided it, do nothing with that new list and finally return the original list you supplied it with.  If you did really want that behaviour (for some reason) you could pipe the result of `List.append [0] free_list` to the `ignore` function which would then make explicit the fact that you are ignoring the result of the `if then` expression.